# Flickering in simple animation chain

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation

I'm trying to animate a pulsting circle. But after the downward scale, there's something of a flickering effect. Any ideas to why that is? Here's my code so far:

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        if (!self.path) {
            self.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(0, 0) radius:7 startAngle:0.0*(M_PI/180.0)  endAngle:360.0*(M_PI/180.0) clockwise:YES].CGPath;
        }

        [self animateCircleUpward];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)animateCircleUpward {

    [CATransaction begin];
        [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{[self animateCircleDownward];}];

        CABasicAnimation * scaleUpwardAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale.xy"];
        scaleUpwardAnimation.fromValue = @(0.7);
        scaleUpwardAnimation.toValue = @(1.0);


        CABasicAnimation *opacityAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
        opacityAnimation.fromValue = @(1.0);
        opacityAnimation.toValue = @(0.6);
        self.fillColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;

        CAAnimationGroup *animationGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
        NSArray *animations = @[scaleUpwardAnimation, opacityAnimation];
        animationGroup.duration = 0.4;

        animationGroup.animations = animations;
        [self addAnimation:animationGroup forKey:@"pulse"];

    [CATransaction commit];
}

-(void)animateCircleDownward {

    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{[self animateCircleUpward];}];

    CABasicAnimation * scaleDownwardAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale.xy"];
    scaleDownwardAnimation.fromValue = @(1.0);
    scaleDownwardAnimation.toValue = @(0.7);


    CABasicAnimation *opacityAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    opacityAnimation.fromValue = @(0.6);
    opacityAnimation.toValue = @(1.0);
    self.fillColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;

    CAAnimationGroup *animationGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
    NSArray *animations = @[scaleDownwardAnimation, opacityAnimation];
    animationGroup.duration = 0.4;

    animationGroup.animations = animations;
    [self addAnimation:animationGroup forKey:@"pulse"];

    [CATransaction commit];
}

@end
```

Thanx in advance!

Comment: Did you check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25611323/1953178

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regards to your actual question you likely need to set your CAAnimationGroup's fillMode property to kCAFillModeForward. The default value is kCAFillModeRemoved, so you are likely glimpsing the non-presentation layer between calls back and forth from your Down and Up methods.

That said, it appears that what you're trying to create is a cyclic animation through back and forth calls between your Up and Down methods via CATransaction's completionBlock. This seems an incredibly inefficient approach; why not try something more like:

```
-(void)scaleAndOpacityAnimations
{
    CABasicAnimation *scaleAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale.xy”];
    scaleAnimation.fromValue = @(0.7f);
    scaleAnimation.toValue = @(1.0f);

    CABasicAnimation *opacityAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@“opacity”];
    opacityAnimation.fromValue = @(1.0f);
    opacityAnimation.toValue = @(0.6f);

    CAAnimationGroup *scaleAndOpacity = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
    scaleAndOpacity.animations = @[scaleAnimation, opacityAnimation];
    scaleAndOpacity.autoReverses = YES;
    scaleAndOpacity.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
    //OP had no value indicated for the duration in posted code, I’m including it here for completion
    scaleAndOpacity.duration = 0.5f;

    [self addAnimation:scaleAndOpacity forKey:@“pulse”];
}
```

Which will simply repeat infinitely many times without having to instantiate new CAAnimations on each cycle.